# Want to transfer file from private on-premise Instance (VM) to google cloud storage without internet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, data-transfer, google-cloud-storage, on-premises-instances

I want to transfer 2TB of files from my on-premise VM(which does not have internet connection)  to google cloud storage. I have established shared VPC and my private connectivity are there. I don't want to enable internet on my on-premise VM , How can I transfer the files from On-premise VM to google cloud storage without internet.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud offers the Transfer Appliance to transfer data to the cloud without using a network connection to the Internet.

[Google Cloud Transfer Appliance](https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/docs/4.0/overview)

Order the device. Once it arrives, copy your data to the device and ship back to Google. Google then loads the data into Cloud Storage.

Pricing: varies. The base fee is $300.00 plus shipping ($120+)